# How to overcome missing timezone implementation in the Mono WASM runtime

Tags: c#, uwp, webassembly, uno-platform

If I try to print `DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay` in Uno, Wasm, and UWP will print two different times. Wasm in UTC and UWP in current culture. How can I make sure in both cases I get Local time?

Comment: If its a bug in the system you'll probably need to wait but if its an emergency you could get the current TZ somehow and then offset the time just before display and it would cause it to be offset from the UTC time and appear as local time... depending on how you format it at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this issue as well. To resolve use javascript. When wasm is detected use Uno.Foundation.WebAssemblyRuntime.InvokeJS.

```
    var getTime = Uno.Foundation.WebAssemblyRuntime.InvokeJS("javaTime()");
```

In a javascript file in your wasm WasmScripts folder

```html
function javaTime() 
{
    var date = new Date();
    return date.toLocaleTimeString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Update 2020/07/15**: This is now fixed as part of the [Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap package v1.3](https://github.com/unoplatform/Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap/releases/tag/1.3.0).

[This is a known issue](https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/15260) in mono for WebAssembly, which will be fixed once this [Uno.Wasm.Bootrapper PR](https://github.com/unoplatform/Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap/pull/242) passes.